# telebot - в нескольких файлах .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Создаю телеграм бота на python 3.8 c помощью библиотеки pyTelegramBot.
При /start бот оправляет 4 главное кнопки.
Хочу чтоб каждая кнопка была в отдельном файле и в этом файле была цепочка действий.

Пока код такой:

main.py

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from buts import but1


BUTTONS = config["BUTTONS"]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    keyboard.row(BUTTONS['but1'], BUTTONS['but2'])
    keyboard.row(BUTTONS['but3'])
    keyboard.row(BUTTONS['but4'], BUTTONS['but5'])

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    elif message.text == BUTTONS['but1']:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Переход на but1.start')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, but1.start)
```

файл but1:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from func import *


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config["TOKEN"]["token"])


def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Text start')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start2)


def start2(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'функция start2')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start3)

def start3(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'функция start3')



bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(filename='./.handler-saves/step1.save')
bot.load_next_step_handlers(filename='/.handler-saves/step1.save')
```

Бот доходит до функции start в файле but1, а дальше возвращается на главную.

Скажите, как мне перейти после функции start, в функцию start2?

Comment: так вызовите start2() в start()

Comment: Если вызвать start2() в start(), то бот не будет ждать ответа пользователя, а просто отравит ему сообщение из 1й и 2й функции. 
А мне нужно, что бы он ожидал ответа